# parse json with value of xml like structure

Tags: json

using jackson2, java
have a json as follows and need help how to parse the value which is in a xml like structure with tags attributes and value. jsonml does not seem to ending tags and so forth but this does.

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "label": "complexvalue",
    "value": "[example uid=\"147366048682873771\" description=\"Example description\"]examplevalue[/example]"
  }
```

I can parse it as string by removing special chars and then splitting them but want to find a better way using jackson2.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did not want to elaborate since, this question or similar question has been answered in the following link: [JSON to XML 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056419/json-corresponding-to-an-xml-with-attributes), [JSON TO XML 02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977979/converting-json-to-xml-in-java)