# How can I retrieve tag attributes from an HTTP XML request in Django REST?

Tags: django, xml, django-rest-framework, django-views, xml-parsing

I'm trying to send an XML file as a payload over HTTP to a Django development server on my local machine. I have no issues sending HTTP POST requests with JSON payloads and I understand that XML functionality does not come with Django REST framework out of the box, so I installed `djangorestframework-xml`. I used a parser decorator in my api view function definition like so:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@parser_classes([XMLParser])
def my_view(request):
    if request.method =='GET':
        pass
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return Response({'received_data': request.data})
```

The issue is, the way the data is structured, the information I need to parse is stored as tag attributes, like so:

```
<CEF>
    <Element>
        <p x="1" y="2"/>
    </Element>
</CEF>
```

And when it is received by Django, `request.data` does not include attribute tag data:

```
{
    "received_data": {
        "Element": {
            "p": null
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a header I could add to the HTTP request to preserve the xml tag attribute data?
Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

I tried different configurations for the tag data, but ultimately, I have no control over the data source and the way the data is structured in the xml file.

Comment: It is possible xml.etree.ElementTree to parse in Python but you needs to decide how to convert attribute of XML to  JSON. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056419/how-would-i-express-xml-tag-attributes-in-json

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution for this, so a short description here in case someone ever needs it.

What worked for me was using the DRF built-in FileUploadParser rather than the XMLParser for `my_view` function. As per [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser), I included the appropriate header to the request: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=upload.xml`.

This allowed DRF to receive the entire XML file in the request, tags attributes included. The file can then be parsed via `xml.etree.ElementTree`, as was suggested by the first comment to the question.